# Special algorithm related to complete graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

There is a complete graph $K_{n}$ and natural number $k:k<n$.

My goal is to study marked edges.

Let:

- $f(G)$ is a set of marked edges of graph $G$
- $\mathbb{A}$ is a set of  $k$-cliques in $K_{n}$
- algorithm in this case is a finite set of steps. In every step we mark some new edge.
- $AL$ is a set of algorithms such they mark at least one edge of every $k$-clique

> I would like to calculate: $$X=min\{|f(K_{n})|:max\{A_{i}\in \mathbb{A}:|f(A_{i})|\}={k\choose2},f(K_{n})\in AL\}$$

It may seems familiar to the following:

$Y=min\{|f(K_{n})|:max\{A_{i}\in \mathbb{A}:|f(A_{i})|\}={k\choose2}\}=|E(T(n,k-1))|+1$

The term of the right side of equation is cardinatlity of set of edges of Turan's graph.

Is it possible to colearate $X$ and $Y$?

I have an idea to take techniques from theory of condinational extremum and use it in discrete world. Also it seems useful to study how Turan figured out his idea with maximalisation edges in graph. Do you know such PDF-s?

Finally i suspect that the best algorithm such satisfy these conditions is following.

1. Mark maximal independent set of edges.
2. Mark next edges so that number of cliques already marked would by minimalised.

Regards.

Comment: Which set of algorithms are you considering?

Comment: I mean algorithm in my case is a selection of marked edges, but later i wrote algorithm as a process with steps which is also a selection of marked edges.

Comment: I mean that your definition of $X$ depends directly on which algorithms are in the set $AL$.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understeand you. $AL$ is a set of such selected edges of $K_{n}$ that every $k$-clique has at least one marked edge.

Comment: What you've written in the question is "$AL$ is a set of algorithms".  Also, as far as I can tell, $Y$ shouldn't be $|E(T(n,k-1))| + 1$, but rather $\binom n2 - |E(T(n,k-1))|$ (for $n$ sufficiently large). If you want to mark at least one edge of every $k$-clique, the minimal way to do that is to mark the *complement* of the Turan graph - partition the vertices into $k-1$ approximately equal sets and mark all edges within a set. This also satisfies the condition that $|f(A_i)| = \binom k2$ for some $A_i \in \mathbb A$, provided any of the sets have size at least $k$.